# Pandas: Swapping specific column values within one Dataframe and calculate its weighted averages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, split-apply-combine

There exist the following dataframe:

| year | pop0 | pop1 | city0 | city1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 20 | 40 | Malibu | NYC |
| 2018 | 8 | 60 | Sydney | Dublin |
| 2018 | 36 | 23 | NYC | Malibu |
| 2020 | 17 | 44 | Malibu | NYC |
| 2019 | 5 | 55 | Sydney | Dublin |

I would like to calculate the weighted average for the population of each city pair as a new column. For example, the `w_mean` for Malibu / NYC = (23+20+17)/(36+40+44) = 0.5.

Following is the desired output:

| year | pop0 | pop1 | city0 | city1 | w_mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 23 | 36 | Malibu | NYC | 0.5 |
| 2019 | 20 | 40 | Malibu | NYC | 0.5 |
| 2020 | 17 | 44 | Malibu | NYC | 0.5 |
| 2018 | 8 | 60 | Sydney | Dublin | 0.113 |
| 2019 | 5 | 55 | Sydney | Dublin | 0.113 |

I already sorted the dataframe by its columns, but I have issues swapping the 3rd row from NYC/Malibu to Malibu/NYC with its populations. Besides that, I can only calculate the `w_mean` for each row but not for each group. I tried `groupby().mean()` but didn't get any useful output.

Current code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'year': ["2019", "2018", "2018", "2020", "2019"], 'pop0': [20,8,36,17,5], 'pop1': [40,60,23,44,55], 'city0': ['Malibu','Sydney','NYC','Malibu','Sydney'], 'city1': ['NYC','Dublin','Malibu','NYC','Dublin']})

new = data.sort_values(by=['city0', 'city1'])
new['w_mean'] = new.apply(lambda row: row.pop0 / row.pop1, axis=1)
print(new)
```

Comment: How do you determine which city is city0 and which is city1? For example, if Sydney and Dublin switched places then the w_mean would be 8.846.

Comment: That is true. The other possibility would be to just sum up the values with the same city pair and to insert two new columns (sum_pop0 and sum_pop1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is creating a creating tuples of `(city, population)`, put the two tuples in a row into a list and then sort it. By doing this for all rows, you can extract the new cities and populations (sorted alphabetically by city). This can be done as follows:

```py
cities = [sorted([(e[0], e[1]), (e[2], e[3])]) for e in data[['city0','pop0','city1','pop1']].values]
data[['city0', 'pop0']] = [e[0] for e in cities]
data[['city1', 'pop1']] = [e[1] for e in cities]
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
    year  pop0  pop1  city0    city1
0   2019    20    40  Malibu     NYC
1   2018    60     8  Dublin  Sydney
2   2018    23    36  Malibu     NYC
3   2020    17    44  Malibu     NYC
4   2019    55     5  Dublin  Sydney
```

Now, the `mean_w` column can be created using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to create the two sums and then divide as follows:

```
data[['pop0_sum', 'pop1_sum']] = data.groupby(['city0', 'city1'])[['pop0', 'pop1']].transform('sum')
data['w_mean'] = data['pop0_sum'] / data['pop1_sum']
```

Result:

```
    year  pop0  pop1   city0   city1  pop0_sum  pop1_sum    w_mean
0   2019    20    40  Malibu     NYC        60       120  0.500000
1   2018    60     8  Dublin  Sydney       115        13  8.846154
2   2018    23    36  Malibu     NYC        60       120  0.500000
3   2020    17    44  Malibu     NYC        60       120  0.500000
4   2019    55     5  Dublin  Sydney       115        13  8.846154
```

Any extra columns can now be dropped.

If the resulting `w_mean` column should always be less than zero, then the last division can be done as follows instead:

```
data['w_mean'] = np.where(data['pop0_sum'] > data['pop1_sum'], data['pop1_sum'] / data['pop0_sum'], data['pop0_sum'] / data['pop1_sum'])
```

This will give `0.5` for the Malibu & NYC pair and `0.113043` for Dublin & Sydney.